# Divisibility of the difference between two very large numbers

Tags: modular-arithmetic, euclidean-algorithm

I am learning from chapter 1 of the algorithm textbook known as DPV.

There is a question 1.11 that asks:

Is $4^{1536} - 9^{4824}$ divisible by 35?

The whole chapter is on modular arithmetic, modular exponentiation, Euclid GCD (as far I got so far) so I broke down the first term to

$2^{3072}$ and second term to

$3^{2(2048)} * 3^{2(2048)} * 3^{3(512)} * 3^{2(128)} * 3^{3(64)} * 3^{3(16)} * 3^{3(8)}$ thinking it would lead to some sort of aha moment but the only conclusions I can draw is that the first term's factors are all divisible by 2, the second term's are all divisible by 3 and 35 has factors 5 and 7 so neither is divisible by 35 on its own.  How can I apply any of the modular arithmetic or Euclid's GCD to this problem to solve it?

Comment: Note first that $4\equiv 9\mod 5$, so there is a conclusion to be drawn from that.  Next you have already changed $4^k$ into $2^{2k}$ so consider either using $9\equiv 2\mod 7$ or else $4\equiv -3\mod 7$ and $9^k=3^{2k}$...

Comment: Without going as far as which theorems to use, note that if you find out $4^{1536}\equiv x$ and $9^{4824}\equiv y \bmod 35$ then the divisibility question is whether $x \equiv y \bmod 35$.

Comment: The place to start is to identify the smallest positive integers  $a,b,r,s$ where $4^a \equiv 1\pmod{5}, 9^r \equiv 1\pmod{5}, 4^b \equiv 1\pmod{7},$ and $9^s \equiv 1\pmod{7}.$  Note that if (for example) $4^a \equiv 1\pmod{5}$ and $4^b \equiv 1\pmod{7}$ and if (also) $c$ is any common multiple of **both** $a$ and $b$, then $4^c \equiv 1\pmod{35}.$  Once a value $c$ is identified, then you know that for any positive integer $k, ~4^{(kc)}\equiv 1\pmod{35}.$  Therefore, you would then consider what the least non-negative residue of $(1536)$ is $\pmod{c}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $4^{1536}\equiv 9^{4824} \bmod 35$ then $35$ divides $4^{1536}- 9^{4824}$, otherwise not.

There are various tools that could help you decide this, and if you have heard of [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) and the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) these could certainly help, but with just the idea of modular exponentiation you can investigate the powers of $4$ and $9$ $\bmod 35$ and reach a conclusion.

Successive powers of $4\bmod 35$ look like:
$4^1 \equiv \color{blue}{4},
4^2\equiv \color{blue}{16},
4^3\equiv 64\equiv \color{blue}{29}, 
4^4\equiv 116\equiv \color{blue}{11}, 
4^5\equiv 44\equiv \color{blue}{9}, 
4^6\equiv 36\equiv \color{red}{1}$

Successive powers of $9\bmod 35$ look like:
$9^1 \equiv \color{blue}{9},
9^2\equiv 81\equiv \color{blue}{11},
9^3\equiv 99\equiv \color{blue}{29}
9^4\equiv 261\equiv \color{blue}{16}, 
9^5\equiv 144\equiv \color{blue}{4}, 
9^6\equiv 36\equiv \color{red}{1}$

*(If you know about [modular inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), you can also see from the powers of $4$ that $4^{-1}\equiv 9 \bmod 35$ which is why the two power value sequences are mirror images of each other.)*

And then casting out multiples of $6$ in the exponent allows us to finish the calculations without difficulty; for example $4^{23} = 4^{3\cdot\color{red}{6}+\color{blue}{5}}\equiv \color{red}{1}^3\cdot 4^{\color{blue}{5}}\equiv \color{red}{1}\cdot \color{blue}{9}\equiv 9\bmod 35$.

Comment: How is the 6 being cast out?

Comment: If we continue calculating $4^i\bmod 35$ from $i=7$, the results continue: $4,16,29,11,9,1,4,16,29,11,9,1,\ldots$ So if we think about a large exponent, we can step back through this repeating pattern by any multiple of $6$ to get to a value calculated. I tried to illustrate this in the calculation of $4^{23}\bmod 35$, showing that it's the same as $4^5\bmod 35$.